# Is the root of $x^5-x-1$ rational or irrational?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am wondering whether the unique real root of the polynomial $x^5-x-1$ ($1.1673\ldots$) is rational or irrational. Is it possible to show that it is either rational or irrational?
Also, can it be expressed in any other way than "the root of $x^5-x-1$"? For example, by $n^{th}$ roots?

Comment: Do you know the rational roots theorem?

Comment: Have you heard of the [rational root theorem](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/rtnlroot.htm)? If there is a rational root of the polynomial, then it must be one of the roots suggested by the theorem.

Comment: If it were rational, it would be $1$ or $-1$, by the *rational roots theorem*.

Answer (score 4):

If it is $p/q$, a reduced fraction, then $p^5-pq^4=q^5$, hence $p|q$, a contradiction to being in reduced form unless $p|1$. In that case, $q^5\pm q^4=1$ which is also impossible, since then $q|1$.

Answer (score 1):

If it were rational then according to Rational Roots Theorem, the roots would be $\pm 1$ now when you substitute 1 or -1 in equation the equation doesn't give 0, so this equation has no rational roots.

Answer (score 1):

By the rational roots theorem, it has no rational roots. In ["Solving Solvable Quintics" by Dummit](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X/S0025-5718-1991-1079014-X.pdf) it is specifically given a case for polynomials $x^5 + ax + b$ to be solvable in radicals; to be solvable, the resolvent $f_{20}(x)$ must have a rational root, where

$$f_{20}(x) = x^6 + 8ax^5 + 40a^2x^4 + 160a^3x^3 + 400a^4x^2 +
(512a^5-3125b^4)x + (256a^6-9375ab^4) $$

If I have not tragically erred in calculation, this polynomial has no rational roots, so $x^5-x-1$ cannot be solved in radicals.